# Appending to a Pandas Dataframe - flat matrix

Tags: pandas, dataframe, append

Trying to append to a pandas:

```
 df=[]          
 df = pd.DataFrame(columns = FEATURES) 
 df = df.append({
     '_DayOfMonth':_DayOfMonth,
     '_MonthOfYear':_MonthOfYear,
     ...
     }, ignore_index = True)
```

Somehow, something goes wrong here. Syntax?

I am running pandas 0.18.1

Comment: Quite a few things are wrong. Take some time and read the documentation. This is quite easy to do. The `append` method does not work the way you have written it. Look up "pandas dataframe from dictionary", and you'll have your answer.

Comment: It works perfect on my friends computer, but not on mine. I got a newer version of pandas (0.18.1). Is there any syntax changes when it comes to append?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Error comes far below, but is the result of a "matrix" which has 43 columns (the 43 features) and 0 rows (due to no appending). My friend has been running the exact same code for a year without problem. The only thing different is that I have a newer version of pandas.                                               
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot

Comment: To plot? Why would `.append` even try to plot? Are you sure the error is being raised by the `.append` function? Or is it the appended dataframe in another function that is causing the error?